# dom-repeat with `<span>` whitespace solution

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer-1.0

I'm wondering if there is a solution other than here:

[How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements?rq=1)

for removing the whitespace when `<span>` tags are in a `<template is="dom-repeat">`.

E.g., suppose we have a dom-repeat generating a table column header:

```
    <th class="asciitable">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_asciiheader]]">
        <span class="asciinumeral">[[item]]</span>
      </template>
    </th>
```

And we want the elements to all appear like, say '12345678', instead of what would happen, '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8'.

The above fits the case of "don't have access to the HTML", because the `dom-repeat` generates the HTML for us, and so we can't put the `<span>` tags on the same line, or use the `<!--\n-->` trick.  Note we have to wrap the data-binding in something, a `<span>` in this case, because Polymer 1.0 requires no spaces before or after data-bindings.

The only thing that seems to work is doing what the link above suggests:

```
.asciitable {
  padding: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.asciinumeral, .ascii {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

but this seems less than ideal.

Comment: Are you sure that the data you're fetching have no space at all?
And also have you tried eliminating the dom space? like between `template` and `span`

Comment: You can use `float: left` instead if that's feasible given your project constraints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about writing everything on one line?

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_asciiheader]]"><span class="asciinumeral">[[item]]</span></template>
```

This should give you numbers without spaces.

Comment: Justin XL, would never have thought of that, thank you :)